# jQuery onLoad x jQuery onDomready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every time I use [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) I see two options to initialize the contents via jQuery: onLoad or onDomReady.

I Tested with most of the scripts I wrote and there was no functional difference. Searching on Google I saw that one of the main differences is that via onLoad, scripts will only start running after all the elements are loaded and that includes CSS external files, JS external files, images and etc., which can be useful if you need to load JS files in a certain order, but at any given moment one of these files makes reference to another who has not been loaded yet, while via onDomReady once the HTML page content is loaded, scripts begin to be loaded already without necessarily others have been.

Got this difference right? Is there any other differences to be studied and perceived?

Comment: @Pilot I don't think you understood my question. I'm not asking for help with code, I'm asking for help to understand the differences between these two approaches. I wrote how far I understood the differences and asked for more information. I want to understand the concepts of each one. Do I have to write a fiddle for that?

Comment: One major difference, jquery ready handler will be fired even handler is set after DOM is effectively 'ready', jquery using internally a promise. Window onload event won't be fired if handler is set after window is loaded. e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/c58a6/

Comment: I saw your fiddle and realized that onDomready can be performed multiple times while onLoad can be performed only once, is that right?

Comment: You can bound multiple onload handlers but if bound after window is loaded, these handlers won't be fired.

Comment: So it ends up being useless to bind multiple onload handlers, right?

Comment: No, why it should be useless? You just have to bind it BEFORE window is loaded, that's what i mean

Comment: Because just one of them will be fired, it would be smarter putting all the code in one onLoad handler I guess.

Comment: Again no, all will be fired: http://jsfiddle.net/c58a6/1/

Comment: So why in your first fiddle the onLoad handler didn't fire? And in this second fiddle seems to me that acts just as onDomready if our concern is just about funcionality.

Comment: Oh, no I get it, you edited your comment and added "You just have to bind it BEFORE window is loaded, that's what i mean". I think you could write an answer showing your fiddles and the differences between them, is more likely that people will read and **learn** from answer than from comments.

Comment: First one, and that was point of it, code in jsfiddle is wrapped already inside onload event, check dropdownlist on left. So window onload handler set here is not fired. Second one, no wrapper is used, so code is read as part of HEAD (could be BODY too, doesn't matter here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making comment as answer:

> One major difference, jquery ready 'pseudo' event will be fired even handler
>   is set after DOM is effectively 'ready', jquery using internally a
>   promise. Window onload event won't be fired if handler is set after
>   window is loaded. e.g:  http://jsfiddle.net/c58a6/

It should be then noted that there is no in-build equivalent of jQuery document ready event. For example, `DOMContentLoaded` in-build event won't be fired if settled after the DOM is ready.

Comment: Could you explain a little further about what you meant with "jquery using internally a promise"? Does it have something to do with [this](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)?

Comment: Ya, that's it. But if you don't know the concept of promise and async behaviour behind it, could be a little hard to explain it (at least from a guy as me). You could check jQuery source and search for `readyList` which is the deferred object used which then expose the promise interface. The difference between a deferred object and a promise is that a promise cannot be resolved manually. But like i said, could be quite long to explain it all